# const_cast const STL container, is it undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I know that use of `const_cast` won't introduce undefined behaviour (i.e., it's safe to use), as long as the variable you're `const_cast`ing wasn't originally defined as `const` or if it was originally defined as `const` you're not modifying it via its `const_cast`ed alias.

However, It is also known that most STL containers (e.g., `std::vector`, `std::set`), allocate their internal buffers dynamically. Based on this fact I think that is impossible for a `const` defined `std::vector` to be placed in read-only memory.

Naturally, if the above holds I come to the assumption that such kind of STL containers even if they're defined as `const`, e.g.,:

```
std::vector<int> const v;
```

`const_cast`ing them and altering them via their `const_cast`ed alias is legitimate and won't cause any undefined behavior.

Does the above assumption holds or I'm wrong?

Comment: If the standard says it is UB, it is UB. Optimizers use this to do all kind of crazy stuff that assumes `const` objects won't be modified.

Comment: Notice, that in case of constant vector, compiler is not required to dynamically allocate memory (_avoiding allocation_ standard clause) and, in fact, it is possible to place constant vector completely in static read-only memory.

Comment: @101010 I think you selected my answer as "solution" a little too fast. It is not yet (as I'm writing this) a real answer to your question. So far I've just addressed the assumption that dynamically allocated memory must necessarily be mutable.

Comment: If you want an object to be modifiable, don't say that it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard explicitly points out that casting away `const` for an object created via `new const T`, and modifying it, is Undefined Behavior.

E.g., the C++11 standard contains this example in its §7.1.6.1/4:

> ```
> const int* ciq = new const int (3); // initialized as required
> int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq); // cast required
> *iq = 4; // undefined: modifies a const object
> ```

Examples in the standard are non-normative, just examples, and can be wrong. For example, in C++03 nearly all examples that used `<iostream>` were wrong (at that time it was formally necessary to also include `<ostream>`, but that was not the intention of the committee), and the expression examples in C++03 §5/4 were wrong, saying the behavior was unspecified rather than undefined (which might have reflected an original intention). However, the above example is correct.

This shows that dynamically allocated memory needs not be mutable: that modifying it, can have Undefined Behavior.

However, when e.g. a `std::string` is created, its allocation of a buffer (if any) occurs during execution of a constructor, at which point the object is not yet `const`, and the buffer is not allocated as `const`. So the buffer, if one is allocated, is not originally `const`. But regarding this particular example the `std::string` may use the small buffer optimization where it uses storage directly in the object, which would then be originally `const` (potentially allocated in read only memory). And this goes to the rational for the rule that *no* originally `const` object can be modified.

---

In addition to the read-only memory scenario, the rationale for UB includes that it can give compilers optimization possibilities.

As [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) notes in [a comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014031/const-cast-const-stl-container-is-it-undefined-behavior/35014570#comment57754729_35014031),

> **”**  Optimizers use this to do all kind of crazy stuff that assumes `const` objects won't be modified.

Breaking the assumptions of the optimizer by modifying an originally `const` object, can have disastrous and effectively unpredictable consequences.